# How to call an Excel VSTO function from an External Application?

Tags: automation, vsto, excel-2010

I am looking for a way I can automate an Excel VSTO Document level solution, to be called from an external application, similar to the VBA approach like "xlApp.Run("WorkBook", "MacroName") which we use to auto mate VBA solutions. As this will be a document level solution, Remoting or Webservices are not options. I am using VSTO 2010 and Framework 4 targeting Excel 2007 and 2010 versions.

Say, I have a Document Level Solution with a workbook named "TestBook" which contains a VSTO based class "MyClass" with a static function "GetData(string connection)" I am looking for a way to make a call to GetData function, from an external application. The solution itself will be loaded into excel by the external application too using Application.Workbooks.Open method.

To summarize: I am trying to find a way to get a reference to an object (ideally) and make a call to a function from a Document level solution after loading it. I am trying both ways like (External App)->(Addin)->(Document level object) but the route (External App)->(Document level Object) would be ideal.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could fire up excel and kick off the macro using the win32OLE interface if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: This link may help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/3e58f337-6bd7-4c1f-a6d6-d5030f9c64c3/

Comment: Yes.. it is possible to call a function with some Caveats from an Application level add-in. But I am looking to hold of objects in a document level solution.

@Smack: That link explains how to how to get reference to and Object in an Addin. The second part to reach Document level object I am still trying to find.

Comment: @Pynner:I am trying to find an alternative with VSTO to eliminate Macros.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to go about this a bit differently...

The call a method the way you want you might a to resort to something called a "COM Automation AddIn" and implement a UDF this way.

You can then just place the call to your method as a formula inside any sell of that workBook - Excel eveluates that formula by calling your implementation. You can even tell Excel to reevaluate it.

Another option might be to build the functionality as a so-called RTD-server which is referenced in your workbook...

For some information see these links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa662931%28office.11%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140060%28office.10%29.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2008/11/13/Rtd3.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140059%28v=office.10%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.rtd%28v=office.11%29.aspx
- http://exceldna.codeplex.com/workitem/5902 (free library to ease the development)
- http://www.add-in-express.com/docs/net-excel-automation-addins.php and http://www.add-in-express.com/docs/net-excel-rtd-servers.php (commercial library to ease the development)

Comment: Thanks for your response. However my problem is not about calling a method in VSTO addin from worksheets. We can use ExcelDNA and can manage to talk to the Installed VSTO addin. My challenge is here to get hold of a VSTO object in a document level customization from an external C# project. This is the last and critical piece of the puzzle I am looking for an answer so that we can stop using VBA.